# How to pass parameter of filename(file name) from folder path (pdf file) into a href tag in asp.net using vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I would like to pass parameter in url (a href tag) by passing filename(of the file, pdf file) from a folder path in asp.net. How can I do this?

Here is my syntax for getting the folder path

```
//Getting file name of the file
Dim fileName As String = Request.QueryString("ID")

//File directory
Dim PDFPath As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("PdfPath") & "\" & fileName & ".pdf"
```

and heres is in the interface

```
  <li><a href="http://www.website.my/" target='_blank'>View PDF</a></li>
```

how should I write it in my href attributes?

Comment: Is the value of `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("PdfPath")` a path on the server's disk, like "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\PdfFiles"?

Comment: Yes , sort of @AndrewMorton

Answer (score 1):

If you change the `<a href="http://www.website.my/" target='_blank'>` into an ASP.NET [HyperLink control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink?view=netframework-4.8), you will be able to set its attributes in the code behind.

So, use

```
<li><asp:HyperLink ID="pdfLink" Text="View PDF" Target="_blank" runat="server" /></li>
```

and in your code

```
Dim PDFPath As String = IO.Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("PdfPath"), fileName & ".pdf")
pdfLink.NavigateUrl = "http://www.website.my/pdfFolder/" & filename & ".pdf"
```

(assuming that `PDFPath` is going to be used for something else).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I believe this will generate `ViewState` for this Hyperlink control which may not be necessary and can be undesirable.

Comment: @Airn5475 It will be tiny. The OP can disable ViewState by using `ViewStateMode="Disabled"` in the @Page directive if necessary. ViewState is not evil.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, the PDFPath is for the system to get into the directory of the folder path. What I'm stuck with right now is how can I link the file name of the pdf file and display it in the interface via a href tag?

Comment: @lara 1) What do you mean by "the system"? 2) Are the PDFs in a directory which is not under the web site's directory? Is it intended that access to them is restricted somehow?

Comment: 1) The system here refer to the web application. 2) Yes. It does not in the website's directory. 3) It does not mentioned any restriction. @AndrewMorton

Comment: @lara Perhaps you could look at [Virtual Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory) as I think that may work well for this case. Using that makes it appear that a separate directory is in the website.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [ASP.NET Inline Expressions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/976112/introduction-to-asp-net-inline-expressions-in-the-net-framework) to reference the value in the code behind.

**Code Behind** (per my comment):

```
Public Class MyPage Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Public Property PDFPath As String

    Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim fileName = Request.QueryString("ID")
        Me.PDFPath = $"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("PdfPath")}\{fileName}.pdf"
    End Sub
End Class
```

**ASPX Page**

```
<li><a href="<%= PDFPath %>" target='_blank'>View PDF</a></li>
```

Comment: Why does it hovers "PDFPath is not declared"? this is in .aspx files. I declared the pdfpath in aspx.vb. @Airn5475

Comment: I think you'll need to make `PDFPath` a `Public` property in your code behind and don't forget to compile your code.

Comment: I already moved it outside of protected sub but it stills unavailable... @Airn5475

Comment: @lara I converted my sample to VB.Net, but it may not be perfect syntax.  The `PDFPath` should be at the code behind class level, not inside of any method.

Comment: Hello @Airn5475 , the code works but when i click the link, it shows about:blank only. it doesnt open any pdf file. but when i copy my pdfpath and paste in the browser, it works. it does not work when we click the link

Comment: @Lara what is your full `<a>` tag html? The rendered version from the actual page, not the aspx page version.

Comment: `<a href="<%= PDFPath %>" target="_blank">View PDF</a>` Did you mean this one? @Airn5475

Comment: Not quite, in your browser, open up DevTools and copy the HTML that actually appears on the page.